# Java Scanner cannot read nextInt() unless enter is pressed / new line character

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

My program for the coding challenge produces the correct output, however, it requires me to press enter a second time for it to work. Here is [the programming challenge](http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/pairs-with-positive-negative-values/0).

It prints out the first line just fine but requires me to press enter again for it to work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int testCases = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < testCases; i++){
            int size = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            int[] arr = new int[size];
            for(int x = 0; x < size; x++){
                arr[x] = sc.nextInt();

            }
            sc.nextLine();
            if(size > 1){
                solve(arr);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("0");
            }
        }
    }

     private static void solve(int[] arr) {
         for(int i =0 ; i  < arr.length; i++){
             arr[i] = Math.abs(arr[i]);
         }
         Arrays.sort(arr);
         for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
             int f = i + 1;
             if(arr[i] == arr[f]){
                 System.out.print((arr[i] * -1) + " " + arr[i]);
             }
         }
         System.out.println();      
     }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to read in multiple integers on one line?

Comment: Click on the link it has the input. I am trying to paste it here, however, stack over flow is autoformatting the input. http://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/pairs-with-positive-negative-values/0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo)

Comment: It appears to be working in this [Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/j7eTw4) (other than a few missing spaces in the output).

Comment: This question has been asked at least a thousand times in SO.

Comment: @user3437460 It's not a duplicate of that. They have seemingly the opposite problem, where it requires them to press enter an extra time.

Comment: No matter which one is duplicate of which one. The source of the problem remains the same, there are remaining tokens in the buffer of `Scanner`.